# seperating values from Arributes

Tags: r

I have the following data set. I Would like to keep the Part Number, Material, shape and group and transpose the corresponding values in front of it in new columns

[image]

i am looking to transpose to something like this:

[image]

can someone please help me. i have used melt function but it wont work the way I want to

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't do this.  The data format you are looking for is [untidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) (and fragile) because it includes data in the column names (the suffix to value).  Your data processing will be full of pain and complexity if you go down this route.  Stick with the format you have or change to a format that includes columns for PartNumber, Material, Shape and Group.

Comment: Put a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. List your dataset with dput, e.g. `dput(mtcars)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can reshape the data in this fashion :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group = cumsum(Name == 'part number')) %>%
  mutate(Group = paste0('Value', Group), 
         row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)

#  Name        Value1 Value2 Value3
#  <chr>       <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 part number A1234  B1234  J25610
#2 Material    AL     TI     PL    
#3 shape       CR     RE     TRI   
#4 Group       47     48     42
```

**data**

Please add data in a reproducible format and not as images.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = rep(c('part number', 'Material', 'shape', 'Group'), 3), 
                 value = c('A1234', 'AL', 'CR', 47, 'B1234', 'TI', 'RE', '48', 'J25610', 'PL', 'TRI', 42))
```